# Keras - how can LSTM for time series be so accurate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

SO I'm starting to test LSTM for time series prediction, and I've found a few different notebooks to use with my own data (here's one [example](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-analysis-visualization-forecasting-with-lstm-77a905180eba))

What they all have in common is that they predict one timestep into the future, and do a really good job at matching the test data. I tried forcing an outlier in there, and the prediction almost perfectly matched it:

[image]

What's going on here? There's no way the model can learn this from the pattern of the data since it's a made up point, but supposedly by looking at the previous time steps this model will "know" an outlier is coming next? I must be missing something, because it predicts the data with an outlier just as well as the data without an outlier...

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing in your test data with your training data. Can you post all of the code you are using to train/predict the data?

Comment: I just read through the article, and although they mention a `train/test split` they don't actually include the code for it in the article.